# Unsure how to install Open Sans font

Tags: mosaico, custom

I’m trying to make Mosaico my go-to instead of MailChimp. Our organisation is big on branding conformity and I have to use Open Sans for our newsletters. Is there a simple way to install that font for Mosaico? The existing solutions are confusing me…
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy if you have developer skills as you will need to

1. Add the fonts ttf files on the server
2. clone the mosaic template
3. Include the font in the template

HTH

Pradeep